# UITableView bottom cells are hidden below screen

Tags: ios, uitableview, storyboard

I am building a table view using a storyboard as part of a navigation controller flow. Everything works well as long as all cells can be shown on one page. The problem is that if there are more cells that fit on the screen some of the cells are hidden below the bottom of the screen. I can see them by scrolling further down taking advantage of the bounce effect. As soon as i release the screen, the bottom cell bounces below the bottom of the screen.

I believe that the problem is the frame dimensions on the table view. I have not found a way to change it through the storyboard and have tried to change the dimensions dynamically:

`self.view.frame = CGRectMake (0.0, 20.0, 320.0, 230.0);`

Unfortunately this has no effect in either the viewWillAppear nor viewDidLoad. With the above set height of 230 points, the list should be easily shown, there are 480 - 44 (Navigation bar) = 436 points left for the table.

What am I doing wrong? Am I setting the frame height in the wrong place (viewWillAppear/viewDidLoad)? Is there a way to specify the height in the interface builder when the view height is greyed out?

### Solution: (Copied from comment below)

Digging deeper into the issue with autosizing, the reason for not showing the field, was that the iOS 6 feature "Use Autolayet" was enabled. Then the Autosizing box is not shown in the IB. Disabling "Use Autolayet" actually solved the issue and the scrolling is now alligned with the bottom of the screen.

Comment: If the view height is greyed out, set the view controller size from "inferred" to "freeform"

Comment: decrease the height of the tableView.

Comment: I tried the "freeform" approach, but the height was still ignored.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use Flexible Height for your UITableView.

1. Open you storyboard / nib file containing UITableView.
2. Select Your Table.
3. From the "Utilities", select the "Size Inspector" tab.
4. in the "Autosizing" box, select "Vertical Size Rearrangement".

It will resize your table according to changes in height of parent view.

**EDIT:** Auto-resizing box and properties are not shown when auto-layout is ON.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Unfortunately there is no "Autosizing" box in the "Size Inspector" tab for the UITableView.

Comment: Digging deeper into the issue with autosizing, the reason for not showing the field, was that the iOS 6 feature "Use Autolayet" was enabled. Then the Autosizing box is not shown in the IB. Disabling "Use Autolayet" actually solved the issue and the scrolling is now alligned with the bottom of the screen. Tanks for the hint @SalmanZaidi

Comment: is there any solution to this problem without disabling autolayout? There's a lot of good that comes with autolayout.

Comment: give proper constraints to tableview for width, height, x and y positions.. Autolayout is indeed a great feature if you know how to use that..

Answer (score 0):

your tableview height is greater than the screen height : set the height to screenheight minus any labels at top

set it to 100 for testing to see what i mean.

do it viewdidload and make sure you are not changing it after

Answer (score 0):

Well i don't know about your current view layout,but if you are trying to implement an UITableview within a view controller then another way to do it will be adding a container where the tableview is placed in view.Add the class files for the tableview and then connect the container with the newly added UITableview Controller class for the tableview.
It should be working fine.

Comment: Thanks. Fortunately I found a solution without the work-around.

Comment: Can u post your solution please

Comment: Solution copied into question text